# Integration (unsure if to do it by parts)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am wondering how to integrate the ff: $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\beta^2}t^{3/2}e^{-t^2/\beta^2}dt$$ I tried doing it by parts by assigning $u=t^{3/2}$ and $dv=\frac{1}{\beta^2}e^{-t^2/\beta^2}dt$. However, I realized that this "integration by parts" will never end due to the fact that the power of $t$ will not eventually reduce to $0$. Is there any other way of doing this integration? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try setting $u = \frac{1}{2}t^{1/2}$ and $dv = 2(t/\beta^2)e^{-t^2/\beta^2}\, dt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\beta^2}t^{3/2}e^{-t^2/\beta^2}\,dt$$

Let
\begin{align}
u & = t^2, \\[10pt]
du & = 2t\,dt.
\end{align}
Then you have
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\beta^2} u^{1/4} e^{-u/\beta^2} \frac 1 2\, du.
$$
This is $\Gamma\left(\frac 5 4 \right)$ times a constant that depends on $\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the substitution $v = t^2/\beta^2$, then you can use the Gamma function.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. $x$ in this case is $u$. Thanks. So I guess I have to use gamma then.

Comment: Yes, you have to use the Gamma function.  This is because your problem is equivalent to computing the Gamma function.  I think you get something like $\Gamma(5/4)$, which has no closed form solution.